# Is the expression negative $2n^{3/4} + 2(n-\sqrt{n})^{3/2} + n - 2n^{3/2} $ for all large $n$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove there is some $N$ such that for all $n > N$, it is the case that $$2n^{3/4} + 2(n-\sqrt{n})^{3/2} + n - 2n^{3/2} \leq 0$$

I know that this is true, since I graphed this function on Wolfram. It has one real root, and beyond that root the function is negative. How would I prove this analytically if possible? It seems like the expression is to messy to work with, but perhaps there is a simplification, or argument I am missing that makes the problem easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m:=n^{1/4}$.

The inequality is equivalent to
$$2m^3(m^2-1)^{3/2}  \leq 2m^6-m^4-2m^3$$

Dividing the both sides by $m^3$ gives
$$2(m^2-1)^{3/2}  \leq m(2m^2-1)-2$$

If $m\ge 2$, then the both sides are positive. Then, squaring the both sides gives
$$4m^6-12m^4+12m^2-4\le 4m^6+m^2+4-4m^4-8m^3+4m,$$
i.e.
$$m^2(8m(m-1)-11)+4m+8\ge 0$$

This inequality holds if $m\ge 2$, i.e. $n\ge 16$.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \sqrt{n - \sqrt n} < \sqrt n - \frac{1}{2}  $$
$$ \left( n - \sqrt n \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} < n^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{3}{2} n + \frac{3}{4} \sqrt n - \frac{1}{8}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Taylor series of the expression for large values of $n$. You should get
$$2n^{3/4} + 2(n-\sqrt{n})^{3/2} + n - 2n^{3/2}=-2 n+2 n^{3/4}+\frac{3 }{4}n^{1/2}+\frac{1}{8}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\right)$$ that is to say
$$-2n\left(1 -n^{-1/4}+\frac 38n^{-1/2}+\cdots\right)$$